# How to use `key_glyph` with `geom_jitter`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following does not add anything to the legend:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, y = table, color = cut)) + 
  geom_jitter(key_glyph = draw_key_rect)
```

[image: diamonds plot with missing legend glyphs]

`draw_key_point` works, `draw_key_dotplot` does to.  `draw_key_rect` also perfectly works with geomtries like `geom_line` or `geom_linerange`.  How can I use it with points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the aesthetic `fill` for rect

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_jitter(aes(x=color, y=table,
                  color=cut,
                  fill=cut),
                  key_glyph = draw_key_rect)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Doh. It's always `fill`.